# Ошибка с json (react)

Tags: reactjs, json, api, rest

Запушил проект в github и больше ничего не трогал, утром уже проект выдает ошибку такую. Хотя ничего не менял и если проверить проект по live ссылке с github там всё работает

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puHCm.png]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, прикрепляйте код в виде текста, а не скриншотами

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в редакторе кода в котором вы это смотрите неправильно указан тип файла. Вам нужно указать его как html файл а не как json. Json не может правильно интерпретировать синтаксис html, поэтому и выводит ошибку.